# Webpack - How to configure to have only relative urls as output?

Tags: webpack

When Webpack bundles, all `require("...")` calls to static files become paths like `path/to/myFile.extension`.

**How can I configure so it will be replaced with relative paths like** `../path/to/myFile.extension` **?**

**For instance:**
If I am in `/static/js/bundle.js`, then `require('../path/to/my/static/image.png')` would be replaced with `../media/image.png` rather than `static/media/image.png`.

Comment: post your webpack.config.js file

Comment: It's about 600 lines of code only the `webpack.config.js`. And there is more than one file.. ^^

Comment: upload your project in git and share the url